# How do I remove duplicate items from an array in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, unique, duplicates

I have an array in Perl:

```
my @my_array = ("one","two","three","two","three");
```

How do I remove the duplicates from the array?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can do something like this as demonstrated in [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f):

```
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}

my @array = qw(one two three two three);
my @filtered = uniq(@array);

print "@filtered\n";
```

Outputs:

```
one two three
```

If you are aiming for universality, you should take a look at the `uniq` function. It is included in the core module [`List::Util`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#uniq) as of Perl v5.26.0 (for older versions, use [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)). This function differs from the above sketch in that it treats `undef` as a separate value, different from `''`, and does not issue a warning.

Comment: please don't use $a or $b in examples as they are the magic globals of sort()

Comment: It's a `my` lexical in this scope, so it's fine.  That being said, possibly a more descriptive variable name could be chosen.

Comment: @ephemient yes, but if you were to add sorting in this function then it would trump `$::a` and `$::b`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @szabgab, if that's the case, that's an incredibly bad design decision for `sort` to use non-local variables.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg Welcome to the world of 1987 - when this was created - and almost 100% backword compbaility for perl - so it cannot be eliminated.

Comment: `sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }` is a better implementation since it preserves order at no cost. Or even better, use the one from List::MoreUtils.

Comment: @vol7tron means "backward" compatible, sorry it was bugging me ;-)

Comment: Perl v5.26.0 onwards, `List::Util` has `uniq` , so MoreUtils wouldn't be needed

Comment: Will this keep the order of selected items unchanged? Can be this method used for a sorted array to preserve the order?

Comment: @Ωmega The relative order of unique items is preserved.

Answer (score 129):

The Perl documentation comes with a nice collection of FAQs.  Your question is frequently asked:

```
% perldoc -q duplicate
```

The answer, copy and pasted from the output of the command above, appears below:

---

Found in /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pods/perlfaq4.pod

**How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?**
(contributed by brian d foy)

Use a hash. When you think the words "unique" or "duplicated", think
"hash keys".

If you don't care about the order of the elements, you could just create the hash then extract the keys. It's not important how you create that hash: just that you use "keys" to get the unique elements.

```
   my %hash   = map { $_, 1 } @array;
   # or a hash slice: @hash{ @array } = ();
   # or a foreach: $hash{$_} = 1 foreach ( @array );

   my @unique = keys %hash;
```

If you want to use a module, try the "uniq" function from
"List::MoreUtils". In list context it returns the unique elements, preserving their order in the list. In scalar context, it returns the number of unique elements.

```
   use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

   my @unique = uniq( 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7 ); # 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
   my $unique = uniq( 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7 ); # 7
```

You can also go through each element and skip the ones you've seen
before. Use a hash to keep track. The first time the loop sees an
element, that element has no key in %Seen. The "next" statement creates
the key and immediately uses its value, which is "undef", so the loop
continues to the "push" and increments the value for that key. The next
time the loop sees that same element, its key exists in the hash and
the value for that key is true (since it's not 0 or "undef"), so the
next skips that iteration and the loop goes to the next element.

```
   my @unique = ();
   my %seen   = ();

   foreach my $elem ( @array )
   {
     next if $seen{ $elem }++;
     push @unique, $elem;
   }
```

You can write this more briefly using a grep, which does the same thing.

```
   my %seen = ();
   my @unique = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @array;
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3F

Comment: John iz in mah anzers stealing mah rep!

Comment: I think you should get bonus points for actually looking the question up.

Comment: I like that the best answer is 95% copy-paste and 3 sentences of OC. To be perfectly clear, this **is** the best answer; I just find that fact amusing.

Answer (score 71):

Install [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/) from CPAN

Then in your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my @dup_list = qw(1 1 1 2 3 4 4);

my @uniq_list = uniq(@dup_list);
```

Comment: The fact that List::MoreUtils is not bundled w/ perl kinda damages the portability of projects using it :( (I for one won't)

Comment: @Ranguard: `@dup_list` should be inside the `uniq` call, not `@dups`

Comment: @yassinphilip CPAN is one of the things that make Perl as powerful and great as it can be. If you are writing your projects based only on core modules, you're putting a huge limit on your code, along with possibly pourly written code that attempts to do what some modules do much better just to avoid using them. Also, using core modules doesn't guarantee anything, as different Perl versions can add or remove core modules from the distribution, so portability is still depending on that.

Comment: Perl v5.26.0 onwards, `List::Util` has `uniq` , so MoreUtils wouldn't be needed

Answer (score 25):

My usual way of doing this is:

```
my %unique = ();
foreach my $item (@myarray)
{
    $unique{$item} ++;
}
my @myuniquearray = keys %unique;
```

If you use a hash and add the items to the hash. You also have the bonus of knowing how many times each item appears in the list.

Comment: This has the downside of not preserving the original order, if you need it.

Comment: It is better to use [slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) instead of `foreach` loop: `@unique{@myarray}=()`

Answer (score 11):

Can be done with a simple Perl one-liner.

```
my @in=qw(1 3 4  6 2 4  3 2 6  3 2 3 4 4 3 2 5 5 32 3); #Sample data 
my @out=keys %{{ map{$_=>1}@in}}; # Perform PFM
print join ' ', sort{$a<=>$b} @out;# Print data back out sorted and in order.
```

The PFM block does this:

Data in `@in` is fed into `map`. `map` builds an anonymous hash.  `keys` are extracted from the hash and feed into `@out`

Answer (score 9):

The variable `@array` is the list with duplicate elements

```
%seen=();
@unique = grep { ! $seen{$_} ++ } @array;
```

Answer (score 9):

## Method 1: Use a hash

Logic: A hash can have only unique keys, so iterate over array, assign any value to each element of array, keeping element as key of that hash. Return keys of the hash, its your unique array.

```
my @unique = keys {map {$_ => 1} @array};
```

## Method 2: Extension of method 1 for reusability

Better to make a subroutine if we are supposed to use this functionality multiple times in our code.

```
sub get_unique {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}
my @unique = get_unique(@array);
```

## Method 3: Use module `List::MoreUtils`

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
my @unique = uniq(@array);
```

Answer (score 4):

That last one was pretty good. I'd just tweak it a bit:

```
my @arr;
my @uniqarr;

foreach my $var ( @arr ){
  if ( ! grep( /$var/, @uniqarr ) ){
     push( @uniqarr, $var );
  }
}
```

I think this is probably the most readable way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers pretty much summarize the possible ways of accomplishing this task.

However, I suggest a modification for those who *don't* care about *counting* the duplicates, but *do* care about order.

```
my @record = qw( yeah I mean uh right right uh yeah so well right I maybe );
my %record;
print grep !$record{$_} && ++$record{$_}, @record;
```

Note that the previously suggested `grep !$seen{$_}++ ...` increments `$seen{$_}` before negating, so the increment occurs regardless of whether it has already been `%seen` or not. The above, however, short-circuits when `$record{$_}` is true, leaving what's been heard once 'off the `%record`'.

You could also go for this ridiculousness, which takes advantage of autovivification and existence of hash keys:

```
...
grep !(exists $record{$_} || undef $record{$_}), @record;
```

That, however, might lead to some confusion.

And if you care about neither order or duplicate count, you could for another hack using hash slices and the trick I just mentioned:

```
...
undef @record{@record};
keys %record; # your record, now probably scrambled but at least deduped
```

Comment: For those comparing: `sub uniq{ my %seen; undef @seen{@_}; keys %seen; }`  Neat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seems the uniq function needs a sorted list to work properly.

```
use strict;

# Helper function to remove duplicates in a list.
sub uniq {
  my %seen;
  grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}

my @teststrings = ("one", "two", "three", "one");

my @filtered = uniq @teststrings;
print "uniq: @filtered\n";
my @sorted = sort @teststrings;
print "sort: @sorted\n";
my @sortedfiltered = uniq sort @teststrings;
print "uniq sort : @sortedfiltered\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using concept of unique hash keys :

```
my @array  = ("a","b","c","b","a","d","c","a","d");
my %hash   = map { $_ => 1 } @array;
my @unique = keys %hash;
print "@unique","\n";
```

Output:
a c b d