# remove duplicate values for a key in hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have the following code

```
chdir("c:/perl/normalized");
$docid=0;
my %hash = ();
@files = <*>;
foreach $file (@files) 
  {
    $docid++;
    open (input, $file);    
    while (<input>) 
      {
    open (output,'>>c:/perl/tokens/total');
    chomp;
    (@words) = split(" ");  
    foreach $word (@words)
    {
    push @{ $hash{$word} }, $docid;

    }
      }
   }
foreach $key (sort keys %hash) {
    print output"$key : @{ $hash{$key} }\n";
}


close (input);
close (output);
```

This is a sample output in a file

```
of : 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

it is true since the term "of" for example existed 10(ten ones) times in the first document
however is there a way to remove the repeated values; i.e instead of ten ones I want just one
Thank you for your help

Comment: Before adding it, check if it's already in the hash.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array-in-perl). Please do a search before posting another question of the same ilk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid adding the dups in the first place, change

```
foreach $word (@words)
```

to

```
foreach $word (uniq @words)
```

---

If you want to leave the dups in the data structure, instead change

```
print output"$key : @{ $hash{$key} }\n";
```

to

```
print output "$key : ", join(" ", uniq @{ $hash{$key} }), "\n";
```

---

`uniq` is provided by List::MoreUtils.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );
```

Or you can use

```
sub uniq { my %seen; grep !$seen{$_}++, @_ }
```

Comment: IS there a way to keep a counter for the removed duplicates?

Comment: Best bet might be to use a hash instead of an array, and maintain a count as the value of the hash. `++$hash{$word}{$docid};` Use `keys` to get the doc ids. You'll lose the order, but it can easily be restored using a numerical sort.

Comment: No. You're storing the doc id in an array value (`$hash{$word}[$i] = $docid;`). I suggested you store it in a hash key (`$hash{$word}{$docid} = $count;`), and I showed you how to do it.

Comment: the uniq removes duplicates which is good, but I want to make a counter for removed duplicates, for example the output should be 
1(10) 2(7) 3(2) 4(4) ...etc

Comment: Not only did I hear you the first time, I answered you. If you have problems implementing it, please post a new question. I can't go into details in comments, and I'm not a code writing service.