# Extracting words from file but each word once

Tags: perl

I want to write a **perl** program which reads the file and extracts the dates in it. However if a date passes more than one times I will print it only once. For example:

```
On 01/10/2011 I went home. On 02/02/2012, I
went to my school. On 02/02/2012, I went
to London.
```

The output should be:

```
01/10/2011
02/02/2012
```

I can do it by adding the dates to an array and control it in every time I read an new date. But I am asking for a more efficient way. Is there a logical way to do it? or any data structure in **perl**?

Comment: Pipe the output through `sort -u`?

Comment: I think [this question][1] should solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array-in-perl

Comment: I think there is no way to do it, in the manner what i mention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will scan line by line looking for dates in `\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}` format and save them in hash as keys.

When file reading is done, it prints these unique keys.

```
perl -nE '$s{$_}++ for m| (\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}) |xg;}{say for sort keys %s' file
```

It can be translated to more readable form (plus some checks)

```
use strict;
open my $fh, "<", "file" or die $!;

my %s;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {

  my @dates = $line =~ m| (\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}) |xg;

  for my $date (@dates) {
    $s{$date} += 1;
  }
}

for my $date (sort keys %s) {

  print $date, "\n";
}
```

Comment: To explain what the above answer does: searches through the text using a regex to find all matches in form XX/XX/XXXX and increments that key in a dictionary (implicitly creating it if it doesn't exist).
Then it just prints out the keys from the dictionary. This is basically the same as your suggestion.

Comment: Minor terminology correction: In Perl, the data type used in this answer is called a "hash", not a "dictionary".

Comment: +1 for explanation and serious tone. My answer used the "nearly James Bond" switch for slurping which I think is not safe for Unicode?  It would be nice if most of ```List::MoreUtils``` was in ```List::Utils``` (i.e. CORE)

Comment: you can slurp any binary with `-0777` so unicode should not make any trouble

Comment: How can you filter instead of date create a sequence of all possible 4 letter combinations of each word.

Comment: @pcproff please post a new question, and explain how input and output data should look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to installing a module to do this (I know it seems like overkill) `List::MoreUtils` has a `uniq` method.  Everyone avert your eyes ... it's Friday afternoon, very hot and possibly time to slurp(`-0777`) beer:

`perl -'MList::MoreUtils qw(uniq)' -0777nE '@dates = m|(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})|xg ;  @x = uniq(@dates); say "@x" '  file.txt`

Sorry ;-)

Comment: hm, here it looks for uniq and prints on every line, but it should do these when reading is complete

Comment: Odd, I'm using 5.18. It might be interesting to see if different versions (of ```perl``` and ```List::MoreUtils```) behave differently - ```perlbrew exec``` to the rescue! Anyway your solution is moduleless and uses the butterfly ```}{``` so is the best be default ;-) Cheers!