# Removing redundant array elements

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array containing many hostnames. I want to remove the redundant elements of this array, i.e:

- If duplicate entries exist, one of them is removed.
- If both `www.example.com` and `example.com` are present, `www.example.com` is removed.

Removing duplicates is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array-in-perl), but how do I acheive the second condition?

EDIT: For clarification, I must mention that `www.` may not be the only thing present -- it might as well be `abc.def.ghi.foo.bar.baz.qux` and `foo.bar.baz.qux`, in which case the former gets removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are saying you want to remove elements which suffix is already there. Well we can transform suffix problem into prefix problem. Then we can use feature that in ordered array prefix precede string itself. Then we remove string if previous string is its prefix.

```
my @array = qw(foo.com bar.net www.example.com example.com
            abc.def.ghi.foo.bar.baz.qux foo.bar.baz.qux);
my @result = do {
    my $p;
    map scalar reverse, grep {
        my $x = !defined $p || !m/^\Q$p/;
        if($x) {
            $p = $_;
            $p .= '.' unless m/\.$/;
        }
        $x
    } sort map scalar reverse, @array;
};

use 5.10.0;
say for @result;
```

Comment: Very clever solution.  Missing the edge case where an entry is a substring of another entry but they aren't actually related.  Ex, foo.com and barfoo.com.  Easily solved by adding the following line: `$p = $_ if $x; $p .= '.' if $p !~ /\.$/;`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array-in-perl), in the main `foreach` we map, into the `%seen` hash, generic *already seen entries*.

At `#1` it comes the trick: we know that `$k` is an hostaname, so we check if it starts with `www.` string, better: each key (I mean each `$k`) is forced to start with `www.`.

Near `#2` we you could use other regular expressions to refine `$k` values (trim spaces, remove ending slashes or `http://`, etc.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

my @hostnames = qw(foo.com bar.net www.example.com example.com);
my %seen = ();
my @result = ();

foreach my $k (@hostnames) {
    $k = "www." . $k if not $k =~ /^www\./; #1
    ... #2
    if (not $seen{$k}) {
        push @result, $k;
        $seen{$k} = 1;
    }
}
```

Result is an array with unique `www.` starting hostnames:

```
www.foo.com
www.bar.net
www.example.com
```

Comment: Please have a look at the clarified question, thanks. (It may not be limited to `www.` and may be anything.)