# capturing unique section irrespective of even or odd occurences

Tags: perl

I have a text file where a particular set of consecutive lines appear again and again. I need to trim all the duplicate occurrences and just print the first occurrence alone.

Input:

```
$ cat log_repeat.txt
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554

$
```

The below Perl solution works only when there are odd occurrences,

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/(^total.*)\1//gms ' log_repeat.txt
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554

$
```

and prints nothing when there are even occurrences.  How do I get the first occurrence irrespective of the section repeating odd or even times.

Comment: You can simply load all lines in a array, use `uniq()` function, and then print all elements in array, this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array-in-perl

Comment: @MobrineHayde.. no, I need to get them in order.. also the section can span many lines.. in the given sample, it spans across 3 lines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match your block, multiple times greedily, as long as all that is followed by yet another

```
perl -0777 -wpe's/(total.*)+(?=\1)//s' log_repeat.txt
```

The lookahead ensures that one (last one) remains since it doesn't consume its match.

Or, keep the first match, by discarding it with `\K`, and remove others

```
perl -0777 -wpe's/(total.*?)\K\1+//s' log_repeat.txt
```

Note that `.*?` that must be used here has differences with `.*`, while probably not practical ones.

Comment: I left out `^` (and thus `/m`) as it takes a great conspiracy to have another `total` inside a line _and_ the same pattern between pairs of them; it's kinda a little impossible -- or, it doesn't make sense.  However, the `^` _is_ informative there and it doesn't hurt adding it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the substitution `s/(^total.*)\1//gms` deletes pairs of blocks.
You can fix this by only deleting a single block at a time using a lookahead:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(^total.*)(?=\1)//gms' log_repeat.txt
```