# How to remove duplicates items in list (Raku)

Tags: raku

FAQ: In Raku, how to remove duplicates from a list to only get unique values?

```
my $arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0];
# desired output [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use The built-in [unique](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/unique)

```
@arr.unique  # (1 2 3 0)
```

3. Use a [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash) (alias map, dictionary)

```
my %unique = map {$_ => 1}, @arr;
%unique.keys;  # (0 1 2 3) do not rely on order
```

2. Use a [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Set): same method as before but in one line and optimized by the dev team

```
set(@arr).keys
```

- **Links:**

  - Answer on [Roseta Code](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Remove_duplicate_elements#Raku)
  - Hash solution on [Think Perl6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491980559)
  - Same question for [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array-in-perl), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363) -> always same methods: a [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash) or a [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Set)

Comment: Note that the `.unique` solution is probably the most performant *and* preserves order.